# How to pass multiple header in Apache Benchmark

Tags: rest, header, apachebench

I need to pass multiple header in `Apache benchmark`.

I have searched on SO and googled also,but no luck so far.

```
ab -n200 -c100 -H 'clientId:test-client;token:93e6acff-2ef9-4c85-9d0b-c9948a8ee93b' http://127.0.0.1/oauth2/user/client/
```

Comment: If it's anything like cURL, you can just use `-H` multiple times. Here's a page with an example: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-appleosx-bsd-curl-sending-http-host-header/

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
ab -n200 -c100 -H "clientId:test-client"-H "token:93e6acff-2ef9-4c85-9d0b-c9948a8ee93b" -v 2 http://127.0.0.1/oauth2/user/client/
```

`-v` show request header